# Return the first index of sublist if a given string is in any of the sublist

Tags: python, search

```
Market = [[1, 'apple', '45'], [2, 'banana', '76'], [3, 'apple', '67']
def search(data: List[list], search: str) -> List[int]:
"""
Return a list of IDs(first index) of fruits whose names contain search
"""
```

Desired output:

```
>>> get_fruits_containing(Market, 'Apple')
[1, 3]
>>> get_bridges_containing(Market, 'bana')#part of name of fruit
[2]
"""
```

I tried 
if any(search in s for s in Market): but didn't work. It should accept upper case or lower case.

Comment: Did you even try something?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a function like:

```
def get_fruits_containing(l,i):
   return [x[0] for x in l if i.lower() in x[1]]
```

List comprehensions are your friend :-).

Now your querying is working:

```
>>> get_fruits_containing(Market, 'Apple') # Works with uppercase too.
[1, 3]
>>> get_fruits_containing(Market, 'bana')
[2]
```

Comment: Thanks but It should accept if the search word is Apple regardless of lowercase upper case.

Comment: Works. Accepted :)

Comment: @Comp Happy to help, :-), 